# Looking for an example @WebService that exclusively jakarta.*

Tags: jax-ws, java-metro-framework, jakarta-migration

`I am migrating a web application from Java8/Tomcat8 (J8T8) to Java11/Tomcat10 (J11T10).  I have a handful of integrations with other systems that utilize SOAP/REST.  Needless to say, this has been a journey.  I've worked through several road blocks and have done the following so far:

- Modified source code replacing "javax." with "jakarta."
- Used eclipse migration tool to convert 3rd party jar byte code from "javax." to "jakarta."
- Used maven plug-ins to invoke wsgen and wsimport on @WebService classes.

The latter leads leads to the main issue.

I am unable to find an example use of @WebService that makes exclusive use of jakarta packages, and is void of any use of, or dependency on, javax packages.  With (J8T8) I use web.xml and sun-jaxws.xml to declare listeners that bind a URL to an implementation. With (J11T10) the listener class is no longer available, but all the literature states that annotations are all that is required to achieve binding.  There are a plethora of examples of @WebServlet that are exclusively jakarta, but I've been searching for @WebService, and "javax" keeps showing up. My prototype is simple - but it doesn't respond. (Code to follow, as soon as I figure out how to format it)

Comment: @WebService public interface TestWSInf { public String speak (); }

Comment: @WebService (endpointInterface = "com.test.TestWSInf",wsdlLocation="wsdl/TestWSSeervice.wsdl")
public class TestWS implements TestWSInf
{
 public String speak () { return "Hello"; }
}

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
        xmlns = "https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
        xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation = "https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
        version = "5.0"
        metadata-complete = "false"
>
    <display-name> Welcome to Test</display-name>
    <description> Welcome to Test</description>
</web-app>

Answer (score 0):

An example was right in front of me on the Eclipse foundation web site.
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/metro-wsit/4.0.0/getting-started/getting-started.html
This site includes a link to a sample project:
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/metro-wsit/4.0.0/getting-started/download/wsit-jaxws-fromjava.zip
Equally important is the step to include/install the shared libraries in Tomcat:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/metro/metro-standalone/4.0.0/metro-standalone-4.0.0.zip
By following the tutorial I was able to get the sample to run.  Once I had it running, I then applied equivalent configuration to my main project and was able to get that running.  In order to do so, I used maven dependency tree to find out what existing dependencies I had to remove in favor of the jar files I downloaded into the shared lib.